# android elipsized textview doesn't work if to place textview after listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I've found very strange behaviour with elipsized textview. It doesn't scrolls text if to place textview after listview for example. And if i place textview at the beginning of layout it works. What could it be?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--
    <TextView
            android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
            android:id="@+id/MarqueeText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
-->


    <include layout="@layout/reminder_header_item"/>

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_trade_points"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            >
    </ListView>

    <View
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#DADADC" />
    <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
            android:id="@+id/MarqueeText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#DADADC" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My layout

Answer (score 0):

You want scroll,your textView height  must be a wrap_content

if you specified in dp you wouldn't achieve  the target

```
<TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:text="START | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | lunch 20.00 | Dinner 60.00 | Travel 60.00 | Doctor 5000.00 | END"
            android:id="@+id/MarqueeText1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:paddingRight="15dip"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:freezesText="true"/>
```

Comment: wrap_content didn't help. Still the same problem. How can behaveour of textview depend on position on layout. Very strange.

Comment: Anybody knows the answer? Some ideas?